# Solr: LowerCaseFilterFactory not applied in SpellCheckComponent

Tags: solr, spelling, query-analyzer

I'm struggling with the SpellCheckComponent in Solr (tested with solr 4.4 and 4.5). I have a field type defined as follows:

```
<fieldtype name="termSuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^[^A-Za-z0-9ÄÖÜßäöü]*|[^A-Za-z0-9ÄÖÜßäöü]*$)"
        replacement="" replace="all" />
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="60" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" 
        tokenSeparator=" "/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="99" outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" 
        tokenSeparator=" "/> 
</analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Investigating the corresponding field with the solr admin analyzer, I can see, that the field is correctly analyzed in index and in query mode. In especially, it is lowercased.

However, if I use this field in a SpellCheckerComponent, I only get suggestions if the term is provided in lowercase (e.g. "bautrokner" is working, "Bautrokner" is not). The component and the request handler are defined as provided in the solr wiki (I know that the shingles might be not necessary for spelling correction but I am also using the field for auto-suggest - with exactly the same problem):

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<!-- Multiple "Spell Checkers" can be declared and used by this component -->

<!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <str name="field">_termsuggest</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
    <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
    <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
    <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
    <float name="accuracy">0.2</float>
    <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
    <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
    <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
    <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
    <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
    <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
    <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
    <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
    <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
    <!--<float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>-->
    <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float> -->
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">_termsuggest</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

I have searched for similar problems for several hours now but I cannot find any hint what's the problem. I would expect that due to the query analyzer, the query term should be lowercased. But this does not seem to be the case.

Mathias

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved: I missed to add the queryAnalyzerFieldType:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <!-- Multiple "Spell Checkers" can be declared and used by this component -->
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">termSuggest</str>
...
```

If there is no queryAnalyzerFieldType specified, a simple WhiteSpaceAnalyzer is used (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5111).

Mathias